# Uncaught ReferenceError: maxHeight is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

jQuery

```
$(function maxHeight() {
  var maxH = 0;
  var contentH = 'calc(100vh - 79px)';
  $(".left, .middle, .right").each(function() {
    if ($(this).height() <= contentH) {
      $(".left, .right").css('justify-content', 'space-between');
      $(".middle").css('height', '100%');
    } else {
      if ($(".middle").height() > $(".left, .right").height()) {
        $(".left, .right").css({
          'height':'calc(' + contentH + ' - 100px)',
          'justify-content':'space-between'
      });
        $(".middle").css('height',contentH);
      } else {
        maxH = $(".left, .right").height();
        $(".left, .middle, .right").height(maxH);
      }
    }
  });
});
mySwiper.height = maxHeight();
```

The error says: Uncaught ReferenceError: maxHeight is not defined
What's wrong with my code?

**edit**: I divided the questions that I originally wrote here. -> [Code to match the height of the 3 elements in JS, is this correct?
 - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55722440/code-to-match-the-height-of-the-3-elements-in-js-is-this-correct)

Comment: Does it have to be solved by JS? You could match the height of the three boxes with css-flexbox.

Comment: Like @niorad said, why you want to use js? it's doable with css flexboxes...
There is a particular reason?

Comment: @niorad I already use flexbox, but I use swiper and have a problem that the element of the previous slide jumps to the next slide when the browser width/height is changed. So I thought it was necessary to use JS in order to "specify" the slide height and have it read into the swiper.

Comment: @aflyzer I already use flexbox, but I use swiper and have a problem that the element of the previous slide jumps to the next slide when the browser width/height is changed. So I thought it was necessary to use JS in order to "specify" the slide height and have it read into the swiper.

Comment: can you give an example? it'll be easier to help you!

Comment: @aflyzer I'll create a demo that I can actually check in JSFiddle. Please wait a moment.

Comment: @aflyzer Sorry I made you wait. Here is a demo. It doesn't work well now, so when it scroll to the next slide, it ended up overlaps the elements of the previous slide. [FullscreenFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/__R2D2/1Lfkt9bs/embedded/result/) / [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/__R2D2/1Lfkt9bs/)

Comment: @pop You fix the height to 100vh (- header height) but on mobile for example,  your content are bigger than space in your screen (so 100vh) is it why you see content from slide1 into slide2. You need to improve your responsive css. Because on large device it works well...

Comment: @aflyzer Oh I see. Oops, I ended up created JSFiddle while leaving the previous code.. I thought it was a little different. This is the current situation. I'm sorry for confusing you! [FullscreenFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/__R2D2/6Ler1539/9/embedded/result/) / [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/__R2D2/6Ler1539/9/)

Comment: @aflyzer I originally separated the post I was writing here. If you don't mind, please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55722440/code-to-match-the-height-of-the-3-elements-in-js-is-this-correct).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is currently a local function inside the jQuery `$(document).ready()` shorthand of `$(/*function*/)` - therefore, it's not accessible from outside that function. Make it a normal function:

```
function maxHeight() {
  var maxH = 0;
  var contentH = 'calc(100vh - 79px)';
  $(".left, .middle, .right").each(function() {
    if ($(this).height() <= contentH) {
      $(".left, .right").css('justify-content', 'space-between');
      $(".middle").css('height', '100%');
    } else {
      if ($(".middle").height() > $(".left, .right").height()) {
        $(".left, .right").css({
          'height':'calc(' + contentH + ' - 100px)',
          'justify-content':'space-between'
      });
        $(".middle").css('height',contentH);
      } else {
        maxH = $(".left, .right").height();
        $(".left, .middle, .right").height(maxH);
      }
    }
  });
}
mySwiper.height = maxHeight();
```

Answer (score 3):

Delete the $() around your function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fiddle with the basic implementation - https://jsfiddle.net/3tuvzxwd/1/

Add `display: flex; flex-direction: row` on the parent container and it will work